# Is there a way to give parallax background effect to a pivot page in WP 8.1 RT?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, pivot, winrt-xaml, parallax

As in the title, is there a way to give the parallax effect like in a Hub control to a pivot? Windows Phone 8.1 RT. WinRTXamlToolKit has a parallax control but it only works for a scroll viewer.

Comment: I would love to see this. But you should know that any parallax implementation in W8.x is a performance killer. Since you indicate RT specifically (on ARM) I imagine the performance impact to be even greater that normal - overall, I might not recommend this to you. But, yes, this can be done. Just measure the HorizontalOffet of the internal ScrollViewer of the Pivot control. Then translate the background with a .75 multiple of the same value.